# how to average a set of columns and exclude other specific columns in R using the summarise command?

Tags: r, mean, summarize

I'm breaking my head here with academic work. I have a data.frame with several numeric columns. I am using the command `summarize` and `group_by` in R to perform the average calculations of my data frame.

I tried with the code `summarize (across (where (is.numeric), mean), -c(Mes, year_date)`, but it calculates the average of the entire data.frame and in addition, it creates a new column `-c (Mes, year_date))`, I would like some numeric columns to be excluded from the media calculation, but continue on the data.frame.

Note that I tried `-c(Mes, year_date)` to exclude these two columns from the average calculation, but it didn't work.

I tried

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

sample_station <-c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','A','B','C','A','B','C')
Date_dmy <-c('01/01/2000','08/08/2000','16/03/2001','22/09/2001','01/06/2002','05/01/2002','26/01/2002','16/02/2002','09/03/2002','30/03/2002','20/04/2002','04/01/2000','11/08/2000','19/03/2001','25/09/2001','04/06/2002','08/01/2002','29/01/2002','19/02/2002','12/03/2002','13/09/2001','08/01/2000','15/08/2000','23/03/2001','29/09/2001','08/06/2002','12/01/2002','02/02/2002','23/02/2002','16/03/2002','06/04/2002','01/02/2000','01/02/2000','01/02/2000','02/11/2001','02/11/2001','02/11/2001')
temperature <-c(17,20,24,19,17,19,23,26,19,19,21,15,23,18,22,22,23,18,19,26,21,22,23,27,19,19,21,23,24,25,26,29,30,21,25,24,23)
wind_speed<-c(3.001,6.332,9.321,10.9091,6.38,10.5882,10.5,10.4348,10.3846,10.3448,10.3125,8.35,10.2632,10.2439,10.2273,10.2128,10.2,10.1887,10.1786,12,10.1613,10.1538,10.1471,10.1408,10.1351,10.1299,10.125,2.36,10.1163,10.1124,10.1087,11.2,10.102,10.099,10.0962,10.0935,10.0909)
esp<-c(11.6,11.3,11,10.7,10.4,10.1,9.8,9.5,9.2,8.9,8.6,8.3,8,11.2,10.9,10.6,10.3,10,12.8,12.5,12.2,11.9,11.6,11.3,11,4.36,4.06,3.76,3.46,3.16,2.86,2.56,2.26,1.96,1.66,1.36,23)
volum<-c(300,300,300,300,300,300,300,300,250,250,250,250,250,250,400,400,400,400,400,105,105,105,105,105,105,105,105,105,105,81,81,81,81,81,81,81,81)

df<-data.frame(sample_station, Date_dmy, temperature, wind_speed, esp, volum)%>%
  mutate(Date_dmy = dmy(Date_dmy)) %>%
  mutate(year_date = floor_date(Date_dmy,'year'))%>%
  mutate(Ano=year(Date_dmy))%>%
  mutate(Mes=month(Date_dmy))%>%
  mutate(Epoca = ifelse(Mes %in% 4:9,'dry','rainy'))%>%
  group_by(sample_station, Epoca, Ano)%>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean), -c(Mes, year_date))
```

I have several columns that I don't want to be averaged (even if they are numeric). For exemple, columns `esp` and `volum`.

update

Exit expectation

[image]

Comment: For `sample_station == "A", Ano == 2002, Epoca == "rainy"` you have 4 values of `esp`. If you want to keep the column but do not want to summarize, what is the expected output? That important information is missing from the edit. The same goes for `volum`.

Comment: My question doesn't really make sense, because when applying `group_by` I will have a reduction in the number of lines, that is, they will be grouped by similarity (repetition) according to `sample_station`. `Epoca` and `Ano`. In this way, there will be loss of data `Mes`, as they will not participate in any operation `group_by` and `summarise`

Comment: @Ronak rightly commented that when using `(c (where (is.numeric)), mean)` only the numeric columns will be calculated. In other words, my problem was the Date that was included as `<num>`, but now it is `<date>`.

Comment: There is really no answer to a question that doesn't make sense. I consider closing the question, as it is not intelligible.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are summarising only part of the data, you need to specify what data (rows) of the un-summarised data you want to maintain. In your example, you don't want to summarise `Mes` and `year_date`, however you have multiple values within each group (`sample_station`, `Epoca`, `Ano`), of these `Mes` and `year_date` columns.

Which values of these unsummarised columns do you want to keep?

If you want to keep all values of the unsummarised columns, you may want to include `Mes` and `year_date` inside `group_by(sample_station, Epoca, Ano)` before summarising.

Alternatively, you may use `mutate()` rather than `summarise()` to get summary values in a new column for each row of the original dataframe, then choose your rows from there.

Update:
Again, with your edited post including desired output, what values do you expect for `Mes`. For example, when `sample_station == 'A'`, `Epoca == 'rainy'` and `Ano == 2000`, you have values for `Mes` of `1` & `2`, and the same `year_date`. `summarise()` wants to calculate one single summary value for this group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `across(c(where(is.numeric), -Mes)`. Note that `year_date` is not included in the calculation as it is not of class numeric and also because it is included in `group_by`.

You can also combine multiple `mutate` statements into one.

If you want to exclude certain columns from the average calculation but want to keep it in the dataframe you need to decide which value do you want to keep. For example, to keep the 1st value you can use `first`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data.frame(sample_station, Date_dmy, temperature, wind_speed)%>%
  mutate(Date_dmy = dmy(Date_dmy),
         year_date = floor_date(Date_dmy,'year'),
         Ano=year(Date_dmy),
         Mes=month(Date_dmy),
         Epoca = ifelse(Mes %in% 4:9,'dry','rainy')) %>%
  group_by(sample_station, year_date, Epoca) %>%
  summarise(across(c(where(is.numeric), -Mes), mean),
            across(Mes, first))
```

Comment: I do not want their average to be calculated, but to be maintained.

Comment: i try `summarise(across(c(where(is.numeric), -c(Mes, wind_speed), mean)))`, but error in R

Comment: I don't want them to be excluded from the data.frame

Comment: Yes, I tested it, but `first` only works for a column and not for a set. How can I show the expected output? Would I edit the question?

Comment: ok, i edited the issue with exit expected